# NetLogo Random values based on probabilities in list

Tags: netlogo

I try to figure out, how to create an output that has an equal distribution on the random sample. Based on the code snippet below, the function creates three random numbers for three items in a list. This values gets than compared to each other, and the maximal value of them, gets count. However I am trying to figuring out how to control the randomness by a probability for example 50% (50) 25% (25) 25% (25) N=100.

```
to numberGenerator

  let i 0
  set counter_red 0
  set counter_blue 0
  set counter_green 0

  while [i < 100] [
    let numberS_red1 random-float 1
    let numberS_blue1 random-float 1
    let numberS_green1 random-float 1

    let usedcolors [red blue green]
    let OPstrength1 ( list numberS_red1 numberS_blue1 numberS_green1)
    let strategies (map list usedcolors OPstrength1)

    print strategies

    if (numberS_red1 > numberS_blue1) and (numberS_red1 > numberS_green1)
    [set counter_red counter_red + 1]

    if (numberS_blue1 > numberS_red1) and (numberS_blue1 > numberS_green1)
    [set counter_blue counter_blue + 1]

    if (numberS_green1 > numberS_red1) and (numberS_green1 > numberS_blue1)
    [set counter_green counter_green + 1]

    set i i + 1
    ]

  print counter_red
  print counter_blue
  print counter_green 

end
```

> counter_red = 26
>
> counter_blue = 36
>
> counter_green = 38

Answer (score -1):

you can implement a new function using the netlogo random-normal command which assigns a color. Documentation for the function is at [link](http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dict/random-reporters.html)

Comment: Using `random-normal` is typically a very bad idea when trying to create a function for fixed proportions like this, because it's hard to control the proportions in different ranges. Instead, you should be recommending `random-float` (uniform distribution) if the OP didn't want to use the rnd extension. This answer would be improved by actually constructing an example function.